# How do you get Kivy to refresh the size of a widget when the window resizes?

Tags: python, kivy

I have the following code:

```
import logging
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler('waynepaint.log'))
logger.handlers[0].setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(name)s:%(message)s'))
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


class CanvasWidget(Widget):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        logger.debug('Size: %r', self.size)


class WaynePaintApp(App):

    def build(self):
        parent = Widget()
        self.painter = CanvasWidget()
        parent.add_widget(self.painter)
        return parent

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WaynePaintApp().run()
```

You can change the size of the window all you want, and yet every time you click the screen, it reports `Size: [100, 100]`. Now, I *know* the size gets larger than that, if you add `from kivy.core.window import Window` and then use `Window.size` you'll see that the window size changes. But not the size of the widget.

How do I get the widget to resize when the Window does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Layout (like BoxLayout) and it will manage the re-sizes for you

```
def build(self):

    parent = BoxLayout() #the only line changed
    self.painter = CanvasWidget()
    parent.add_widget(self.painter)
    return parent
```

When your parent is Widget it doesn't have any functionality on handling its children sizes